# jquery css strange problem with chrome/safari browser

Tags: jquery, css

this is page i'm currently working on: http://devel.spoorle.com/poc/

At the bottom there is a div called footer, which contains 3 other divs: logo_lower, annoucements_online and menu_lower. Two of them have fixed width, logo_lower 406px and menu_lower 329px while annoucements_online gets it width from jquery script:

```
var annoucementsWidth = $(window).width() - $("#menuLower").width() -    $("#logoLower").width();
$("#annoucementsOnline").css("width",annoucementsWidth + "px");
```

For Opera, Firefox and even IE 8 with works perfectly fine, but I have problem with Safari and Chrome. The menu_lower div is not showed... any idea what it might be? I saw somewhere that jquery calculates wrong $(widow).width() for those browsers. I tried to put my code inside $(window).load() but with no success.
Here are the divs:

```
div.logo_lower {
width: 406px;
height: 45px;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

div.annoucements_online {
background: #362f2d;
height: 45px;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
}

div.menu_lower {
background: #362f2d;
width: 329px;
height: 45px;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
overflow: hidden;
}
div.footer {
width: 100%;
height: 45px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 100;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: One more thing I discovered is that when I take 3 pixels from annoucementsWidth, chrome shows property div but it looks like it lack 1 pixel, really weird thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it othere way, simply I make annoucements div smaller by 5px:

```
var annoucementsWidth = $(window).width() - $("#menuLower").width() -    $("#logoLower").width() - 5;
$("#annoucementsOnline").css("width",annoucementsWidth + "px");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the width like this instead of unsing jQuery.

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery needs to go in `$(document).ready()` not `$(window)`. Also, when I test your site on Chrome, I get the same results as Firefox.

If jQuery isn't playing nice, you can always go the [vanilla JavaScript route](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm) ([more info](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow)), although this is more complex as jQuery usually does all the compatibility stuff for you.

Comment: So by saying "Also, when I test your site on Chrome, I get the same results as Firefox." you mean it works fine or there is an error on Firefox?

My code is inside $(document).ready()